# Kotlin Unresolved Reference When Using Library

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I am writing an Android app in Kotlin. I am using [this](https://github.com/mattbdean/Kdown) library.

Following the instructions present at the bottom of the readme, I added the following line:

```
implementation 'net.dean.kdown:kdown:0.4.0'
```

in my "Module: app" build.gradle script.

I also have the line `jcenter()` in my "Project" build.gradle script

I then added the `import net.dean.kdown.*` in my imports in my "MainActivity.kt" file.

As a test, I tried using the library in my onCreate method, as follows:

`val downloader = Kdown();`

But, I'm getting the error "Unresolved reference: Kdown". Also, the IDE is giving the "Unused Import Directive" error, even though, theoretically, I should be using the import to create the "downloader" object.

Why isn't this working?

Here's my build.gradle file for the project.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here's my app module's build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rstudios.vroy1.animefacekeyboard"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'net.dean.kdown:kdown:0.4.0'
}
```

Comment: I'd start with unpacking the JAR you're downloading and verifying that the class is indeed there

Comment: Where can I find the JAR?

Comment: On my machine it's under ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1, I guess the numbers may vary, but the structure should be similar